# How to not display an item in select query?

Tags: sql, ssms

I feel a little stupid asking this because I feel like this is very easy, but for some reason I'm not able to update a query to not select a specific item based on two criteria.

Let's say I have data like this:

```
 ID       Name       Variant     Count1
 110      Bob        Type1       0
 110      Bob        Type2       1
 120      John       Type1       1
```

So as you can see we have two BOB rows with same ID but different variant (type1 and type2). I want to be able to only see one of the Bob's.

Desired result:

```
 110      Bob        Type2
 120      John       Type1
```

So what I've been doing is something like

```
 Select ID, Name, Variant, sum(count1) from tbl1
 where (id not in (110) and Variant <> 'type1')
 Group by Id,name,variant
```

Please don't use COUNT as a criteria, because in my example it just so happens that Count=0 for the row that I don't want to see. It can vary.

I have many rows where I can have multiple instances of the same id with a variety of different VARIANTS. I'm looking to exclude certain instances of ID based on Variant value

UPDATE:

It has nothing to do with latest variant, it has to do with a *specific* variant. So I'm just looking to basically be able to use a clause where i used the ID and VARIANT, in order to remove that particular row.

Comment: You seem to have answered the question yourself.  If there are id/variant pairs you want to exclude, then you can use a `where` clause.  What then is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregating (grouping) the data like you're doing is one way to do it, although the where condition is a little overkill. If all you want to do is see the unique combinations of ID and Name, then another approach is just to use the "distinct" statement.

```
select distinct Id, Name 
from tbl1
```

If you always want to see data from a specific Variant then just include that condition in your where clause and you don't need to worry about using distinct or aggregates.

```
select * 
from tbl1
where Variant = 'Type 1'
```

If you always want to see the record associated with the latest Variant, then you can use a window function to do so.

```
select a.Id, a.Name, a.Variant
from 
    (
        select *, row_number() over (partition by Id order by Variant desc) as RowRank
        from tbl1
    ) a
where RowRank = 1
;
```

If there is not a predictable pattern for exclusion then you will have to maintain an exclusion list. It's not ideal but if you want to maintain this in the SQL itself then you could have a query like the one below.

```
select *
from tbl1
-- Define rows to exlcude
where not (Id = 110 and Variant = 'Type 1') -- Your example
and not (Id = 110 and Variant = 'Type 3') -- Theoretical example
;
```

A better solution would be to create an exclusion reference table to maintain all exclusions within. Then you could simply negative join to that table to retrieve your desired results.

Comment: This is not an answer to my question. Please read again. I have hundreds of rows, and want to exclude a specific item based on those two criteria: ID, and Variant. There might be multiple instances of the same ID with different variant. Even if it was that simple, it still wouldnt resolve it properly if you look at my Desired Result since you are only looking for 'Type1'

Comment: Koosh, you don't mention any specific exclusion criteria in your question. Only that you would like to see one record for each combination of Id and Name. Can you define the rule you want to use for exclusion?

Comment: i added some info below, i need to exclude it based on ID and Variant as there might be multiple instances of the same ID and Variant

Comment: I see that. It's still not clear what the the rule is for picking which record to exclude though. Do you always want to see the latest Variant? In order to codify this, your exclusion rules need to be predictable. Otherwise, you'll end up having to add new criteria to your where clause for every unique exclusion.

Comment: update the question withs ome notes. All i'm saying is that I might have ID 110 appear 30 times in the table with different variants. I want to be able to remove an instance of that ID where a particular Variant equals to any type. not latest, not earliest. It could be in between

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. In that case, a manual exclusion list is really the only way to do it. I have added one last example in my answer to cover that case.

Comment: YES. damn how did i miss that. I don't understand why my query is not working the way it's written, I figured it would work if I included both criteria in paranthesis

Comment: Okay, so your problem was much simpler than I had pictured it. Your where clause was just written incorrectly.

Comment: thanks for clarifying it yes it was so simple that i felt really stupid for asking but appreciate the patience!

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using an exclusion table where you can place the ID and Variant combinations that you want to exclude? ( I just used temp tables for this example, you can always use user tables so your exclusion table will always be available)

Here is an example of what I mean based on your example:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#temp') is not null
    drop table #temp

create table #temp (
     ID int,      
     Name  varchar(20),
     Variant varchar(20),
     Count1 int 
)

if object_id('tempdb..#tempExclude') is not null
    drop table #tempExclude

create table #tempExclude (
     ID int,      
     Variant varchar(20)

)

insert into #temp values 
    (110,'Bob','Type1',0),
    (110,'Bob','Type2',1),
    (120,'John','Type1',1),
    (120,'John','Type2',1),
    (120,'John','Type2',1),
    (120,'John','Type2',1),
    (120,'John','Type3',1)

insert into #tempExclude values (110,'Type1')

select
    t.ID,
    t.Name
    ,t.Variant
    ,sum(t.Count1) as TotalCount
from
    #temp t

    left join
    #tempExclude te
        on t.ID = te.ID
            and t.Variant = te.Variant
where
    te.id is null
group by
    t.ID,
    t.Name
    ,t.Variant
```

Here are the results:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. If there's a need for us to do it with a lot of exclusions, this would definitely be a good fit. but in this case we rarely do this, so i just updated the query!

Answer (score 1):

I think the logic you want is something like:

```
Select ID, Name, Variant, sum(count1)
from tbl1
where not (id = 110 and variant = 'type1')
Group by Id, name, variant;
```

For the second condition, just keep adding:

```
where not (id = 110 and variant = 'type1') and
      not (id = 314 and variant = 'popsicle')
```

You can also express this using a list of exclusions:

```
select t.ID, Name, t.Variant, sum(t.count1)
from tbl1 t left join
     (values (111, 'type1'),
             (314, 'popsicle')
     ) v(id, excluded_variant)
     on t.id = v.id and
        t.variant = v.excluded_variant
where v.id is not null  -- doesn't match an exclusion criterion
group by Id, name, variant;
```